Object and number subtraction negates the number in browser js
Why does {} - 1 give -1 result in browser javascript?
As per my understanding of how type coercion works here, first valueOf() will be called on the {}, which is not a primitive value, so next toString() will be called, which gives [object Object]. That would give us '[object Object]' - 1, so NaN, however it actually results in -1.
In node this seems to work as per my understanding, as the result is NaN there.

Where are you seeing the -1 result? I get NaN: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/5wsqzxn4/. Please add the code that reproduces the problem to the question.

@RoryMcCrossan I get -1 in Firefox in the console — I think it's yet another console weirdness. Probably it;s evaluated as block statement ; -1;

console.log({} - 1)

In the console, for involved reasons, {} - 1 is evaluated as if you had typed
  {
    // no statements
  }
  -1;

It's a block statement followed by the expression -1.
If you type ({} - 1) to force evaluation as an expression, you get NaN.
The console REPL is not simply an expression evaluator; it attempts to evaluate and run anything you type as a sequence of statements. A statement that starts with { is always disambiguated as being the start of a block of statements, never as an object initializer.
